# Obtain current module after it's been overwritten in sys.modules?

Tags: python, ipython, sys, ipdb

I have a script I'm trying to run from the command line:

```
import ipdb
def f(): pass
import pickle
pickle.dumps(f)
```

This is of course simplified. In reality I'm trying to use `f` in a `multiprocessing.Pool`, hence the need to pickle it. With ipython 5.3.0 and ipdb 0.10.2 this yields:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <function f at 0x1071eaaa0>: it's not found as __main__.f
```

I believe this is because IPython is overwriting `sys.modules['__main__']` as described [here](https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/issues/112).

I'd like to work around this problem. One idea I had was to replace `sys.modules['__main__']` with the current module. I could obtain this reference before importing ipdb, but I'd like to avoid that (for rather involved reasons beyond the scope of this question).

Is it possible to get a reference to the current module after it's been overwritten in `sys.modules`? I see that I can get its name (`__main__` in my case) but I don't see how to get its value (other than by looking in `sys.modules`).

Comment: Perhaps a cleaner work-around is to make a separate module?

Comment: True, I think that would work. In my case I need it to be a single file that's run as a script from the command line though.